# Reading and Writing Filestreams C++

Tags: c++, text, file-io, filestream

I'm having a problem getting the user input to be saved into a Txt file. Not sure what I am doing wrong; it is not writing to the file:

```
void Menu::nowShowingDecisions()
{
    switch (userInput)
    {
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        xyPosition(0, 0);
        CAtitleHeader();
        CAtitleMenu();
        getUserInput();
        CAtitleDecisions();

        break;
        return;

    case 2:
    {
        string userName;
        string password;
        {
            ofstream outFile;
            {
                outFile.open("C:\\Test\\Test.txt");
                if (!outFile.good())
                    cout << "File Could Not Be Opened." << endl;
                else
                {
                    cout << "Enter Username:";
                    cin >> userName;

                    cout << "Enter Password:";
                    cin >> password;
                    while (cin >> userName >> password)
                        outFile << userName << password << endl;

                    outFile.close();
                }
            }
        }
        return;
        {
            const int COL_SZ = 10;
            ifstream inFile;
            inFile.open("C:\\Test\\Test.txt");
            if (!inFile.good())
                cout << "File could not be opened" << endl;
            else
            {
                cout << left;
                cout << "Movie Ticket Accounts" << endl;
                cout << setw(COL_SZ) << "User Name" << setw(COL_SZ) << "Password" << endl;
                while (inFile >> userName >> password)
                {
                    cout << setw(COL_SZ) << userName << setw(COL_SZ) <<
                    password << setw(COL_SZ) << endl;
                }

                inFile.close();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Please try to keep your tabbing consistent.  Chaos-tabbed code is hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this block of code

```
             cout << "Enter Username:";
              cin >> userName;             // BEING IGNORED

              cout << "Enter Password:";
              cin >> password;             // BEING IGNORED
              while (cin >> userName >> password) // THIS IS BEING SAVED>
                  outFile << userName << password << endl;
```

You are not writing the first `userName` and `password` to the output file.

It's not clear whether you wanted to really have the `while` loop in there. If you want to write out just the first username and password, you need to change it to:

```
              cout << "Enter Username:";
              cin >> userName;

              cout << "Enter Password:";
              cin >> password;
              if (cin) 
                  outFile << userName << password << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Got confused on the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Reading or Writing to a txt using C++ can be done in a simple way like this.

// writing on a text file

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

 using namespace std;

 int main () 

 {
   ofstream myfile ("example.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
 {
    myfile << "This is a line.\n";
    myfile << "This is another line.\n";
   myfile.close();
 }
   else cout << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

// reading a text file

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

 int main () 

 {
   string line;
   ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
   {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
  myfile.close();
 }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

 return 0;
 }
```